# Which article a/the should be used in API documentation?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, technical

For example:

`some_field` - an/the description of smth

In what cases articles should be/should not be used?

Comment: What do your API documentation standards say? The requirements can vary from company to company. Personally, I prefer to keep things as close to English as I can.

Comment: We do not have any standards. Personally, I prefer to use an article a before nouns at the beginning of a sentence. However, recently I have found that some public API documentation uses an article the before nouns. So, I am confused

Comment: If you see both used, that probably means either is valid and it's a matter of company style or personal choice. It's also possible to not use an article.

Comment: I think it goes deeper than that. Forget about whether it’s an API or not. You’re writing English. Would you use ’a’ or ’the’ in each instance.  And that depends semantically on whether you’re talking about a specific thing or a general instance of a thing.  Have you established the existence of the thing already or is this a new thing?   For example if some function takes ***an*** object and also requires ***the*** length of that object, I’d find it highly unusual to say that the function takes the object and a length because it’s not any length it’s ***the*** length of that ***the*** object.